# how to compare date in database column & date_now, and put result in a column?

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

i have a table in SqlServer which contain's: (ID, item_name, date_time_added)

i want to create a C# code to first: view (ID,item_name, date_time_added) column in datagridview then  calculate (date_time_NOW - date_time_added) and view the result in a new column(named: expire's in:) in same datagridview...

Note: **result would count day's remaining before expiring**

what i've tried so far:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Expire's in:", typeof(int)));

        int countrow = dataGridView1.RowCount;

            for (int i = 0; i < countrow; i++)
            {

                string dateAsString = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                DateTime.TryParseExact(dateAsString , "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out DateTime dateAsString);

                dateTimePicker3.Text = dateAsString;
                DateTime expire_date = dateTimePicker3.Value;

                TimeSpan span = expire_date - DateTime.Now;
                int days = span.Days;
                dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index].Cells[4].Value = days;

            }
```

Note:Code Updated...
Any help will be greatly appreciated..

Comment: Please post your code as requested according [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume the “ExpireDate” field returned from the sql query is a `DateTime` object. If this is the case then it would appear that converting the “date” to a string is unnecessary. Example, given a “future” date, then the difference between todays date and the “future” date can be accomplished as…

```
TimeSpan dif = futureDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
```

Using a `DataTable` proffers the ability to use an `Expression` column, however, I do not think this will work with dates and times. Fortunately, this should not be difficult to implement if the grids `DataSource` is a `DataTable`. Using a “Class” would be another option. This example uses a `DataTable` as a `DataSource` to the grid.

Given this, to make things simple it would appear that a method that takes a `DataRow` from the data table and adds this `TimeSpan` difference may come in handy. It may look something like below…

```
private void SetDifCol(DataRow row) {
  TimeSpan dif = ((DateTime)row["ExpireDate"]).Subtract(DateTime.Now);
  row["TimeToExpire"] = dif.Days + " days " + dif.Hours + " hours " + dif.Minutes + " minutes";
}
```

Given that the `DataTable` has already been filled with the data… the code is going to have to “ADD” this difference column, then loop through each row and calculate the difference between the dates. Therefore, a small method that simply adds this column may look something like below…

```
private void AddDifferenceColumn(DataTable dt) {
  dt.Columns.Add("TimeToExpire", typeof(string));
}
```

Next is the loop through all the rows in the `DataTable` and simply call the `SetDifCol` method on each row.

```
private void CalculateDateDif(DataTable dt) {
  foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
    SetDifCol(row);
  }
}
```

This will work as expected when the data is loaded, however, what if the user “changes” one of the “ExpireDate” values in the grid? In this case, we would need to wire up one of the grids cell change events. Specifically the grids `CellValueChanged` event. This event will call the `SetDifCol` method if the “ExpireDate” value changes in that row…

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "ExpireDate") {
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ExpireDate"].Value != null) {
      DataRowView row = (DataRowView)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
      SetDifCol(row.Row);
    }
  }
}
```

Putting this all together may look something like below…

[image]

```
DataTable GridTable;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  GridTable = GetTable();
  FillTable(GridTable);
  AddDifferenceColumn(GridTable);
  CalculateDateDif(GridTable);
  dataGridView1.DataSource = GridTable;
  dataGridView1.Columns[3].Width = 180;
}


private DataTable GetTable() {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("ExpireDate", typeof(DateTime));
  return dt;
}
private void AddDifferenceColumn(DataTable dt) {
  dt.Columns.Add("TimeToExpire", typeof(string));
}

private void FillTable(DataTable dt) {
  dt.Rows.Add("ID1", "Name1", new DateTime(2019, 12, 31));
  dt.Rows.Add("ID2", "Name2", new DateTime(2019, 8, 31));
  dt.Rows.Add("ID3", "Name3", new DateTime(2019, 4, 30));
  dt.Rows.Add("ID4", "Name4", new DateTime(2019, 1, 31));
  dt.Rows.Add("ID5", "Name5", new DateTime(2019, 4, 12, 21, 38, 00));
}

private void CalculateDateDif(DataTable dt) {
  foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
    SetDifCol(row);
  }
}

private void SetDifCol(DataRow row) {
  TimeSpan dif = ((DateTime)row["ExpireDate"]).Subtract(DateTime.Now);
  row["TimeToExpire"] = dif.Days + " days " + dif.Hours + " hours " + dif.Minutes + " minutes";
}

private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "ExpireDate") {
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ExpireDate"].Value != null) {
      DataRowView row = (DataRowView)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
      SetDifCol(row.Row);
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this helps.

**EDIT:**
 to change column type from `string` to `int` to sort numerically.

In reference to the extra question you posted, you commented that *”i want to calculate according to what is inside my db Table”* … There is no code in this question or the other question that shows a data base. How are you getting the data to begin with?

It appears in this question that there IS a NEW `DataTable` `dt` and a column is added to it, however, it is NEVER used. The loop in the code simply adds the difference column to the “GRID” NOT the `DataTable.` My answer “adds” the diffence column to the `DataTable` (which you should do). I recommend you show how you are getting the data from the data base.

In reference to sorting the column, you have already noticed that `string`s that are numbers will not sort properly numerically. This is because they are string… solution… make them `ints`. Using my answer, two changes are need for this. First the creation of the column needs to be an `int` type…

```
private void AddDifferenceColumn(DataTable dt) {
  dt.Columns.Add("TimeToExpire", typeof(int));
}
```

Second a change is needed in the `SetDifCol` method. Since you only want the days difference and any values less than zero should show as zero (0), then the following changes should accommodate this requirement.

```
private void SetDifCol(DataRow row) {
  TimeSpan dif = ((DateTime)row["ExpireDate"]).Subtract(DateTime.Now);
  if (dif.Days >= 0) {
    row["TimeToExpire"] = dif.Days;
  }
  else {
    row["TimeToExpire"] = 0;
  }
}
```

These two changes should sort the column numerically as expected.

Lastly, it should be clear, that IF you want this “difference” column to be reflected in the database… then YOU will have to add the difference column to the database table, THEN, you will need to issue an update command to the database table.

Comment: Thank you so much, it really did help alot.

Comment: i tried the code and it work's perfectly, but how do i apply it on my database's table ? i tried changing FillTable's content but couldn't make it work, thanks in advance

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by… _“apply it on my database's table”_ … are you wanting to “add” this “difference” column to the database? If so, then you will need to add that column to the data base table, however, I can not think of a reason to “save” this difference column… it “IS” a computed value from the existing data. If the date changed in the database, then you would need to also update the difference value and this appears unnecessary. Can you clarify what you are wanting to do?

Comment: no i don't want to save "TimeToExpire" column in database, what i meant was: i want to view database column's in the datagridview and then insert to the datagridview "TimeToExpire" which will count expiredate-datenow.. your code work's but it apply's on given rows (i.e. name1,name2,name3....) not database table row... and sorry for my bad english

Comment: I am not following what you are saying. Your comment… _” your code work's but it apply's on given rows (i.e. name1,name2,name3....) not database table row.”_ … is unclear. If the code is adding the column to the `DataTable` then displaying this in the grid (as the code does), then how is the “database table” going to reflect this change? As I stated previously, I would not save this value in the database. I assume I missing something.

Comment: i want to view my db table in dgv, then use "TimeToExpire" on them

Comment: What do you mean by... _"then use "TimeToExpire" on them"_ ? ... What is "them"?

Comment: i mean my table content

Comment: There are two (2) `DataTables` the “new” one created in the code used for the grid and the `DataTable` that is in the data base. Initially, the code is filling the “new” `DataTable` by calling the database with a query. I am guessing as the posted code shows none of this. The code is “adding” this column to the “new” `DataTable` and displaying it in the grid. If you try and “update” the “database table” with this “altered” table… you may run into problems. Again, which `DataTable` do you want to “see” this “difference” column?

Comment: "the code is filling the “new” DataTable by calling the database with a query. " this one.

Comment: i made a new discussion, hope i explained better there
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55722151/adding-column-expiring-in-to-my-column-that-will-calculate-expiredate-datenow

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you try to put a string into the DateTime value here:

```
DateTime str;
        str=dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
```

If you want to parse string to DateTime the code should look like this:

```
string dateAsString = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                DateTime.TryParseExact(dateAsString, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out DateTime dateAsDateTime);
```

Then you can substract that date from DateTime.Now:

```
TimeSpan span =  dateAsDateTime - DateTime.Now;
```

And finally extract the days from the span:

```
int days = span.Days;
```

OR just do it all in one line:

```
int days = (DateTime.Now - dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index].Cells[3].Value).Days;
```

Comment: i've tried applying your code on mine and now i have this error:
1. use of unassigned local variable 'dateInStringFormat', (code is updated to current one if it can help)

Comment: It's a typo on my part, it should be dateAsString everywhere. Sorry, I updated the anwser as well.

Comment: Also if you want to count days remaining before expiring shouldn't you substract it the other way around? I mean that the date from database will be in the future, so it is bigger than the DateTime.Now. The result will be a negative number of days. I also changed that in the anwser.

Comment: thanks for quick answer, i forgot to mention that the program see's these two as problem too, can u check please... 
"DateTime dateAsString" <<<this,  in last section of:
                (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateAsString, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out DateTime dateAsDateTime);

Comment: I don't quite understand, is this is the full error message you're getting? You can also try less restrictive methods like TryParse or ParseExact, or even Parse. "Exact" in the method name means that it needs an exact format of the date provided so if your date is written as "2019/04/22" or "2019.04.22"  it won't work so it's worth double checking. Maybe you need to change the format.

Comment: Also TryParse and TryParseExact actually have a return value of bool (true if the parse was a success), and Parse do not require date to be in an exact format.  You can find more info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netcore-2.1 (Just be sure to pick the framework you are working on in the top left, I provided a link with .NET Core 2.1 that I'm using.